# http to https issues .htaccess web.config global.asx windows hosting

Tags: .htaccess, asp-classic, web-config, global.asa

I wonder if someone could help. We would like to be able to redirect our website to the https version globally. The SSL certificate is installed and the https version of the site is live and working. I have tried the following methods.

web.config in www root.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="SSL" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$"  />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="https" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

.htaccess in www root with URL rewrites enabled on the hosting provider.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysitedomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have recycled the application pool after and changes and deleted browser cache. Both methods do not work. Is there anyway to try and validate either method to make sure the file is being read as it just doesn't seem to do anything. Is it possible to try with the global asa ? If you need any further information please ask.

Edited to provide more information about hosting environment. 
We are using a shared cloud hosting platform running windows 2003 (this is easily switchable between different platforms) and access is over a web portal. The site runs its own application pool, which we are able to recycle. There is the option to activate and deactivate URL rewrites.. the description here.

*Enabling the "rewrite" module will allow you to utilise Apache mod_rewrite style functionality in a .htaccess file on a Windows or hybrid mode website. For instance a URL such as /store/products/televisions could be rewritten to /store.php?type=products&category=televisions for search engine optimisation. For further information please see the following external URL.*

I am able to hardcode an SSL redirect on a page by page basis but on a global level, no matter what I try whether it's web.config or .htaccess just doesn't seem to pickup.

Comment: Like I said *(before you deleted your previous question)* we don't know your architecture / environment etc. If you just want to redirect http traffic to https then the [solutions provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52857587/692942) should work. Questions not covered that need anwsers, what version of Windows OS and IIS is being run? and do you have access via VPS or is it just through a web panel?

Comment: You also mention `.htaccess` file which [has nothing to do with IIS hosted sites](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/) *(its used by Apache Web Servers)*, so are you even using IIS?

Comment: @Lankymart  Occasionally one finds Helicon's third party isapi rewrite filter installed on IIS which works in conjunction with an Apache style .htaccess file.  I don't really see the point now that Microsoft have a native rewrite module, but I guess some people prefer it

Comment: @John possibly, but i’m not convinced in this case. Second question, still lavking enough detail about their environment.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect website from `HTTP` to `HTTPS`, try following.

if you are using `Linux & cPanel – Force HTTPS using .htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domainname.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And if you are using `Windows & Plesk – Force HTTPS using web.config`

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
       <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
         <match url="(.*)" /> 
         <conditions> 
           <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
         </conditions> 
         <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
       </rule> 
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Don't forget to clear the cache

Comment: Does global.asa interfere with web.config ?

Comment: @Emma No, the `global.asa` is for declaring application and session level event handlers and declaring global type libraries, it has nothing to do with IIS website configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There might be different ways to do that. Simply redirect in the scripts like that

```
<%
   If Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_PORT")=80 Then
      Dim strSecureURL
      strSecureURL = "https://"
      strSecureURL = strSecureURL & Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")
      strSecureURL = strSecureURL & Request.ServerVariables("URL")
      strSecureURL = strSecureURL & "?" & Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")
      Response.Redirect strSecureURL
   End If
%>
```

See [HOW TO: Use ASP to Force SSL for Specific Pages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/239875/how-to-use-asp-to-force-ssl-for-specific-pages)

Comment: Thanks Alex, yes I have been doing it this way instead, obviously not as clean as doing it globally though.